# what is CAN_NART flag behavior on STM32

Tags: stm32, can-bus

I have an STM32 application which on initialization has CAN_NART enabled.
During the application execution, at some point I should disable this flag.

My question is, during execution if I dynamically change this flag, should I re-initalise the CAN on STM32? or is it just a flag which can be set/ unset without re-initialisation?

Comment: "STM32" could mean anything, there are lots of parts and the older ones use a different CAN controller. You need to specify the exact part used. It would also be helpful if you could explain why the text in the manual is unclear.

Comment: I am using STM32F2 series.

Comment: I checked the manual and I could not specifically see anything related to my use case.

Comment: If there is no explicit limitation on modifcation of this register in the manual, the probably you can modify in on the fly. Why don't you make a test?